# My navbar not staying on top, it stick around with scrolling, how to make it stay on top

Tags: html, css

Anyone can help me make my nav stay on top? so it don't stick around, i try every position absolute,sticky,fixed, but is not working is keep following when i scrolling. i not using any framework css, if i use framework css my parallax scroll just broke ._.

<-- Comment -->

ummmm stackoverflow not leeting me post just is mostly codee... sooo this is just random word for me to fill in. test 1 2 3 bla bla bla

https://codepen.io/BlaupilzHD/pen/MWwGpMY

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
    }

    html,
    body {
      background-color: #FEDCC8;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #navbar {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1000;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    nav {
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    label.logo {
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 80px;
      padding: 0 100px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }


    .checkbtn {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      float: right;
      line-height: 80px;
      margin-right: 40px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }

    #check {
      display: none;
    }

    .cv {
      border-radius: 20px;
      margin: 18px 30px;
      padding: 15px 30px;
      color: azure;
      background-color: #2D112B;
      float: right;
    }

    /* Parallax Scroll */

    .parallax {
      -webkit-perspective: 100px;
              perspective: 100px;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: -1500px;
    }

    .parallax__layer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .parallax__layer img {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .parallax__cover {
      background: #2D112B;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 2000px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .parallax__layer__0 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
              transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
    }

    .parallax__layer__1 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
              transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
    }

    .parallax__layer__2 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
              transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
    }

    .parallax__layer__3 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
              transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
    }

    .parallax__layer__4 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
              transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
    }

    .parallax__layer__5 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
              transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
    }

    .parallax__layer__6 {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
              transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
    }
```

```html
            <nav id = "navbar">
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "check">
                <label for = "check" class = "checkbtn">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </label>
                <label class = "logo">My Name</label>
                <button class="cv">Download CV</button>
            </nav>

            <div class="parallax">
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
                    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
                </div>
                <div class="parallax__cover"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: I can see in the given codepen example the  Navbar  consisting of My Name and Download CV is always stays on top. If it is not expected please elaborate your issue.

Comment: i want it to stay on top, not following when im scrolling, i want it absolute, not sticky

Answer (score 0):

Your nav is being sticky due to your  div overflow hidden styling. As per your code you have two divs and they both are absolute mean none of them have their own individual space. Your parallex effect is taking complete visible screen. so nav bar have limited are and unable to sroll. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ummm  sorry i dont get what you mean, what div that overflow my hidden styling is it in the parallax class ? or is it in the navbar class. soo the point is because of my parallax scroll i cant make my navbar stay on top ?